# Expression Blend 2013 RC2 Crashes when loading a Solution with an F# project in

Tags: f#, portable-class-library, blend

I've created a new solution in Expression Blend 2013 RC2 and saved it.
I then opened the solution in Visual Studio 2013 RC2 made some changes and saved it.  I could open the solution in Expression Blend without any issues.

I then created an F# Portable Library project and re-saved the solution.   I can no longer open the solution in Expression Blend as Blend crashes as soon as I open it.

If I attach a debugger it shows a NullReferenceException:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

and the stack trace is as follows:

```
>   Microsoft.Expression.Project.dll!Microsoft.Expression.Project.ProjectService.OpenSolution(Microsoft.Expression.Utility.IO.DocumentReference solutionOrProjectReference = {Microsoft.Expression.Utility.IO.DocumentReference}, bool addToRecentList, bool openInitialScene)  Unknown
    Microsoft.Expression.Project.dll!Microsoft.Expression.Project.Commands.OpenRecentProject.Execute()  Unknown
    Microsoft.Expression.Utility.dll!Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Commands.CommandTarget.ExecuteCommand(string commandName = "Project_OpenRecentProject_1", Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Commands.CommandInvocationSource invocationSource = MenuItem)  Unknown
    Microsoft.Expression.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Expression.Framework.Commands.CommandService.ExecuteCommand(string commandName = "Project_OpenRecentProject_1", Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Commands.CommandInvocationSource invocationSource = MenuItem) Unknown
    Microsoft.Expression.Utility.dll!Microsoft.Expression.Utility.UserInterface.CommandBarButtonBase.Execute.AnonymousMethod__0()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source = {System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher}, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler = null)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object state)  Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd = 5899532, int msg = 49869, System.IntPtr wParam = 0, System.IntPtr lParam = 0, ref bool handled = false)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source = {System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher}, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler = null)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd = 5899532, int msg = 49869, System.IntPtr wParam = 0, System.IntPtr lParam = 0)    Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame = {System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame})  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run()  Unknown
    Microsoft.Expression.Framework.dll!Microsoft.Expression.Framework.ExpressionApplication.RunApplication()    Unknown
    Microsoft.Expression.Blend.dll!Microsoft.Expression.Blend.BlendApplication.Start()  Unknown
    Blend.exe!Microsoft.Expression.Application.Main(string[] args)  Unknown
```

If I remove the F# project. Rebuild and Resave the solution then the solution opens in Blend correctly again.

Is this a known issue?
Is there a workaround to this?

Thanks

EDIT

I didn't add ANY code at all to any of the projects so all the code are simply empty projects with the standard .cs and .fs files you get when you create the solution/project.